# Iframe src is being set Empty

Tags: iframe

I have read few places that Iframe it cant be implemented because of the attacking issues. but I am using this Iframe with different url in another page with different controller, but this time its empty

VF

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:iframe src="{!pdfView}">
            </apex:iframe>
            <apex:facet name="footer">
                <apex:outputPanel >
```

Class

```
pdfView = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+doc.Id+'&headerHeight=null&footerHeight=null#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&zoom=90' ;

  return Page.multiPDFSave;
```

I am not sure why it wouldnt load it

Comment: Have you tried different browsers ? If you are using Chrome, you need to enable display unsafe content option.

Comment: What are you trying to return using Page.multiPDFSave? Are you setting up pdfView value in your constructor or your variable properties?

Comment: @SLman yah that is not the case, I tried that Already, I tried everything they said On google

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty that Page has  <apex:iframe src="{!pdfView}"> in it , that is the one displaying the iframe. So I am coming from different page with the same class into this page to show the iframe